# Separation techniques

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I need to identify separation processes that begin with each letter of the alphabet. I am missing an example for B, J, K, O, Q, X, Y, and Z. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113057/discussion-on-question-by-george-separation-techniques).